# Comparison of two NumPy arrays without order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison

I have to compare two numpy arrays regardless of their order. I had hoped that numpy.array_equiv(a, b) will do the trick but unfortunately, it doesn't. Example:

```
a = np.array([[3, 1], [1,2]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]])
print (np.array_equiv(a, b))`# return false
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some examples of that don't quite match.  At this point your comparison is under-specified.  What if `a` had a `[1,3]` element?  And `b` had a `[2,1]`?

Comment: This search on 'unique rows' gives an idea of the scope of the problem,http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+unique+rows

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.array_equal(np.sort(a.flat), np.sort(b.flat))`

```
In [56]: a = np.array([[3, 1], [1, 2]])

In [57]: b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]])

In [58]: np.array_equal(np.sort(a.flat), np.sort(b.flat))
Out[58]: True

In [59]: b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [60]: np.array_equal(np.sort(a.flat), np.sort(b.flat))
Out[60]: False

In [61]: b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 3]])

In [62]: np.array_equal(np.sort(a.flat), np.sort(b.flat))
Out[62]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably just do:

```
#np.sort can take an axis parameter. For your case we will sort row wise.
np.array_equiv(np.sort(a,axis=0), np.sort(b,axis=0))
Out[178]: True
```